# How to create circle container with border in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, border

As you can notice, the background color of the decoration is slightly overflowing the circular border. I've tried in different ways (e.g. using ClipOval) but the result is always the same.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have just faced the same issue. Easy workaround:

```
     Container(
        width: 28,
        height: 28,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.25), // border color
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), // border width
          child: Container( // or ClipRRect if you need to clip the content
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.blue, // inner circle color
            ),
            child: Container(), // inner content
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[Reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13675)

Comment: this works better than using the border parameter because it doesn't leave white pixels around the circular border

Comment: this won't work if inner colour is to be transparent and show the background.

Answer (score 17):

```
Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.red)
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Container(
            height:80,
            width:80,
            decoration:BoxDecoration(
             
              color:Colors.red,
            borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(50),
              border:Border.all(
              color:Colors.white,
              width:8
              ),
             
            ),
            child:
            Center(child:
            Text("4",
                      style:TextStyle(
                      color:Colors.white,
                        fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize:20
                      )))
```

Container with border

[image: 1]